# Run other commands alongside selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to make a discord bot that starts a selenium thread. It works but the only issue is that I cannot use other commands if selenium takes too long. It will eventually respond to the next command but it's only responds after selenium is finished.

This is what I have:

```
import threading
import discord
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

def start(url):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.close()

@client.command()
async def rq(ctx):
    #if link == None:
        #await ctx.send("Please send a link!")
    await ctx.send("Started!")
    threading(target=start("https://google.com/")).start()

@client.command()
async def sc(ctx):
    await ctx.send("some command")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.run(token)
```

Any solutions would be helpful!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you invoke the thread is incorrect:

```
threading(target=start("https://google.com/")).start()
```

What this does is:

1. Call the `start` function on the main thread, passing it the URL.
2. Wait for the function to finish.
3. Take the returned value (`None`) and pass it as the `target` function to the thread constructor (I think you meant `threading.Thread` there by the way).

So by the time the thread starts, the actual work has already completed on the main thread, and the thread itself does nothing.

The correct way to start a thread and pass it some arguments would be:

```
threading.Thread(target=start, args=("https://google.com/",)).start()
```

Notice how `start` is not being followed by `()`, so we're not calling the function directly; we're passing the function *itself* to the `Thread` constructor. The arguments are given as a tuple to the `args` argument (hence the trailing comma).